# insertion of a list in cassandra python

Tags: python, database, string, cassandra, formatting

I have a table in Cassandra like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS article(
         url text PRIMARY KEY, 
         title text, 
         author text, 
         sources list<text>)
```

And I have an object `Article` with the following method to insert data into cassandra:

```
def save_to_cassandra(self, session):
    session.execute(
        """
        INSERT INTO article (url, title, author, sources)
        VALUES (%s, %s, %s, ????)
        """,
        (self.url, self.title, self.author, ["http://source1.com", "http://source2.com"])
    )
```

The question is what should I use instead of the `????` to format properly the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should use %s for all types of arguments, not just strings**
So use %s, here is the full code

```
def save_to_cassandra(self, session):
    session.execute(
        """
        INSERT INTO article (url, title, author, sources)
        VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)
        """,
        (self.url, self.title, self.author, ["http://source1.com", "http://source2.com"])
    )
```

Source : http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/getting_started.html#passing-parameters-to-cql-queries

Another thing, you should always use Prepared Statements

> Prepared statements are queries that are parsed by Cassandra and then saved for later use. When the driver uses a prepared statement, it only needs to send the values of parameters to bind. This lowers network traffic and CPU utilization within Cassandra because Cassandra does not have to re-parse the query each time.